# Checkout old commit to temporary directory with git

Tags: git

My sources are at `/home/user/Workspace/MyProject`, and the git repository is at `/home/user/Workspace/MyProject/.git`.

Now I want to get an older commit, but get it in `/home/user/Workspace/MyProject_OldCommit`, because I don't want to change anything in directory `MyProject`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
cd /home/user/Workspace
git clone MyProject MyProject_OldCommit
cd MyProject_OldCommit
git checkout <old_sha1>
```

Comment: If it's temporary, `git clone -s` could probably be safely recommended.

Comment: What does `git clone -s` do?

Comment: `-s` may very well be safe here, but for a temporary clone it also isn't likely to provide much benefit. It causes the clone to refer to the objects directory of the original rather than making hard links to the objects. This means that objects created in the original after the clone will also avoid being copied when fetched, but will cause major problems in the clone if objects are deleted from the original.

Comment: History rewriting in git does not remove any files - it creates new ones so linked repositories will not be affected. Only way to corrupt other repository is to mess with git data structures directly

Answer (score 2):

Run this from `/home/user/Workspace/MyProject`:

```
git archive  <old-sha1> | tar -x -C ../MyProject_OldCommit
```

This will create a fresh copy of the commit, without the whole git repository.